# Using a shortcut point to CLI program resulting in not outputing to the current shell, instead of a new window

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

I installed PHP 7.2.1 successfully, and create a simple PHP script:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
```

If I execute the **PHP CLI `.exe` file** directly, everything works fine. The problem is that executing **a shortcut that points to the PHP CLI `.lnk`** doesn't output anything to the current shell, it creates a new PHP CLI window and quit instantly:

```
PS C:\php\php-7.2.1-nts> .\php.exe .\index.php
Hello World

PS C:\php\php-7.2.1-nts> .\php.lnk .\index.php
    (output nothing)
```

I'm so confused about it. Since the `.lnk` shortcut points to the same single one executable file, why there are differences in terms of behaviour between each other?

Comment: Why are you creating shortcut files?

Comment: Shortcuts can have different attributes to the original file.  Have a look at the properties.  Also look at Windows Event Log.